# Soap UI - Changing a property depending on a response

Tags: groovy, soapui, testrail

I have some Soap UI scripts running nicely but I want to improve it by adding support for my Test Tool's API (I'm using TestRail)

I want to have it so once a test has completed in Soap it sends the relevant API request and the test case is updated in my test tool dependent on the response.

My problem is I'm quite new to SOAP and I'm unsure of the best way to handle this. Essentially all I need is a property to be of an integer value depending on the response from a previous test.

e.g. I call a web service and the response comes back with a "success" value of "true"

I want to then have some logic which reads this response, and then changes a test case level property to an integer value of 1 or 2 depending on the response. I will then use this value to pass to my api call within another soap test which will update TestRail.

I'm guessing this will probably lead to Groovy scripting, which I haven't done, I'm just wondering on the best way to handle this as I don't know how to reference the response of another test in a Groovy step.

Appreciate any help in advance :)

Comment: Additionally, another way to approach this may be just some form of script that checks the assertions I've made and sets my integer property depending on whether or not any failures have been detected?

This would require scripting as well I suppose as I don't know how to access Assertion results and validate against them

Comment: Question is little unclear. Would you please clarify what is the response and what logic you want to apply?

Comment: Apparently TestRail has an API http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/start

Comment: Sorry, it may be a little unclear.

Basically, all I need is a final test step which sets a simple test case property depending on whether the previous steps have passed or failed. 

TestRail's API just needs an integer value (1=passed, 5=failed etc) that I pass in a test step.

All I need is to somehow evaluate the previous test steps in my case, and if there are any fails, set my property to 5, or if all pass, set the property to 1. 

That way the final step in all of my tests will just be to pass this value to my step which updates TestRail through its API.

Comment: Take a look at Firefly plugin for ReadyAPI: http://www.agiletestware.com/firefly
It allows to send execution reports to TestRail.
Disclaimer: I work for agiletestware and Firefly is a commercial product